# Making plant/tree care tags general

Tags: discussion

There was one question earlier today on [thinning fruit trees](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/196/thinning-fruit-on-the-tree), and was tagged [fruit-thinning](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fruit-thinning). Since the primary purpose of tags is for archival purposes and easy access to information, I suggest making such tags more general, like [tree-care](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tree-care). The reason is that there's bound to be questions on pruning, fertilizing, etc and it will be easy for a new comer to find all this information under one tag.

Would it be better to have both tags, i.e., the general tag and a more specific tag? What do you guys think?

I forgot to bring this topic to meta before retagging the aforementioned question as [tree-care](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tree-care) . Based on the outcome of this discussion, I'll either rollback or re-edit or leave it alone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Tree-care" is a good tag, but I think it's suitable for general tree care questions. In my opinion, the thinning fruit question is specific to fruit trees and growing fruit as well as a general tree care question. In this case, maybe instead of the tag "fruit-thinning", **two** tags should be used: "tree-care" *and* "fruit-care" or something similar.

Comment: yes, `fruit-care` is a good idea!